# Bash - 2 arguments

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

How do you insert 2 arguments at the same time? so far I could only insert the $filename but

not the $Number of files I want at the same time.

this is the prompt:
"Enter the **file name** followed by the **amount** of that file you want"

```
grep $filename input.txt|head -n$Number;;
```

Comment: Insert read statement in your script i.e. "Enter the file name followed by the amount of that file you want"  read filename Number  grep "$filename" input.txt | head -n"$Number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not following you. Please correct your question.

But most probably you want this:

```
PROMPT_TEXT='Enter the filename followed by the amount of that file you want: '
read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT" filename amount
grep -m "$amount" -- "$filename" input.txt
```